# PostgreSQL - how to drop a user with hyphen in his username

Tags: postgresql

I can't seem to execute `DROP USER username` if the username contains hyphens (-), like for example `user-name`.

I tried a straightforward `DROP USER user-name`, also `DROP USER 'user-name'` but I'm getting: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'user-name'"`.

I would guess I need to use some kind of escaping or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identifiers need to be quoted using double quotes, single quotes are for string literals:

```
DROP USER "user-name";
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Ah, how I missed that is just sad :(. Thanks for a quick reply!